# How to move images one by one using horizontalscrollview in android

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I'm new to android development world. I want to display images one by one in imageView using HorizontalScrollView. I have tried HorizontalScrollView LinearLayout ImageView, but i displaying images continuously.

Comment: Why you want to use HorizontalScrollView, use ViewFlipper or ViewPager

Comment: Is it work for multiple images?

Comment: I am posting something for this just check out ...

Comment: I tried tat too... but it showing only one imageview in my layout.

Comment: so you want that way only, you have posted that in your question itself "I want to display images one by one in imageView".....

Comment: Just try the below answer, I hope you will achieve what you want....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add ViewFlipper in you xml first :-

```
  <ViewFlipper
                android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="6dip" >

            <!--  The child Views/Layout to flip -->

            <!--  Layout 1 for 1st Screen -->
                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >


                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                            android:layout_width="450dp"
                            android:layout_height="450dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/image1" />

                </LinearLayout>

                 <!--  Layout 2 for 2nd Screen -->

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                             <ImageView
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_width="450dp"
                        android:layout_height="450dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/image3" />


                </LinearLayout>


            </ViewFlipper>
```

And then just inflate the ViewFlipper inside your activity :-

```
@Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            {
                         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                         setContentView(R.layout.view_flipper_main);
                         viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.view_flipper);
            }
```

And if you want to show the next image you can simply use :-

```
 // Show the next Screen
                                     viewFlipper.showNext();
```

And if you want to show the previous image you can simply use :-

```
// Show The Previous Screen
                                 viewFlipper.showPrevious();
```

The above code will show one by one image and later you can animate it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/07/implement-gallery-like.html 
is some simple example which has implemented horizontal scroll view to look like image gallery